# Sending multiple buffer images per response - nodeJS, expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, buffer

I am working with raspberry pi. I would like to take two images with a pi-camera (delay of 50ms in between).
After both images are taken, I would like to send both of them to the controller along with response.

What I have tried:

```
app.get('/img', function (req, res) {

 const runApp = async () => {

    const stillCamera = new StillCamera()

    const stillCameraWP = new StillCamera({
        delay: 50
    })

    //To get images with out projection
    const image = await stillCamera.takeImage()

    //To get images with projection
    const image1 = await stillCameraWP.takeImage()

    //sending image to controller
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
    res.send(Buffer.from(image,image1)) 

 }

 runApp()

})
```

I would like to send both image and image1 along with the response.

Answer (score 0):

In the response object, you can try to send data as JSON, like

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify(
 { 
  image : Buffer.from(image),
  image1: Buffer.from(image1)
 })
);
```

Since you are using `await` in your callback, you must use `async` in request handler like this,

```
app.get('/img', async (req, res) => {
  //callback implementation here
})
```

Similarly, in `runApp` you must use await in creating `StillCamera` objects, like:

```
const runApp = async () => {

    const stillCamera = await new StillCamera()

    const stillCameraWP = await new StillCamera({
        delay: 50
    })
```

Comment: ok, so at the controller end if we have to save it ,we can parse it and then save .
is it right?

Comment: Yes. I am very much sorry for the late reply.